# There is an open contractible covering anytime?

Tags: manifolds

Let $M$ be a simply-connected smooth manifold with dimenison $n$.

Then, is there an open covering $\{U_i\}$ of $M$ such that each $U_i$ is contractible?

Comment: Google "good cover".

Comment: Isn't it obvious, from the definition of manifold?

Comment: Note that $\R^n$ is contractible, hence every locally euclidean space has a cover by contractible neighborhoods. The good covers mentioned by Moishe Kohan have the further property that intersections of the covers are either empty or contractible as well. Their existence is more dubious to me than that of the cover you originally asked for...

Comment: So, in other word, any open covering is contractible?

Comment: No. open covers need not be contractible. That is in no way a consequence of what PrudiiArca said. For example, the circle is an open cover of itself, and is not contractable.